# Javascript property comparison

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to check if the value inside an input control and the value of a property in an element are the same. When both values are an empty string I am getting a result of true which is basically saying that empty string is not equal to empty string. This is incorrect my result variable should be false.

```
var result = txtEntryPhone.value != selectedMember.Phone;
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add a plunkr or something?

Comment: Try changing your comparison to use the `!==` operator. It checks that value and type are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible thing to check:

Is one of the values containing an invisible character? Check the length to confirm:

```
console.log(txtEntryPhone.value.length);
console.log(selectedMemeber.Phone.length);
```

If both of the elements objects, eg `...value = new String('')`:

```
console.log(typeof txtEntryPhone.value);
console.log(typeof selectedMemeber.Phone);
```

Comment: You sir are a legend. I have no idea why but selectedMemeber.Phone.length was 1 instead of 0